# CSS definition stripped from final bundle

Tags: css, angular, webpack, angular-cli

I'm using Angular CLI and it's preconfig'ed webpack bundle. I have a bit of HTML that's inserted into a template via `[innerHTML]` and want to apply styling to it, but I notice that the final `styles.bundle.js` doesn't contain the style I write. I assume webpack is smart and strips out the CSS definition since it's not in any template, but being added via JS.

In my template I simply have this:

```
<div [innerHTML]="message"></div>
```

Which gets a value in the controller such as:

```
this.message= '<p class="notice">Your account was successfully activated!</p>';
```

And while I have `.notice` defined in my .less file, it doesn't appear in the style bundle. When I had the notice class previously in the template itself, it worked fine.

Is there a way for me to keep this from happening? Should I be coding differently? Or is the problem elsewhere and not what I think it is?

Comment: _"Should I be coding differently?"_ We don't even know what your code looks like now.

Comment: I guess when I posted this, I figured this was more a theory question than a specific example, but I'll throw in what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

Since the HTML being added by `innerHTML` is not directly in the scope of Angular, I needed to add `/deep/` selector before `.notice` in my less file, to make sure children can access the CSS value.